# Columns addition

Tags: ruby, bash, awk

I try to do sums in columns (values between the ",") depending on the date and time.

exemple:

```
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:02:07,"0","52",50.0,5.3,44.7,5.6,100.0,0.23,0.03,0.20,6.3,4.5
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:02:07,"1","52",36.9,22.3,14.6,39.9,100.0,0.59,0.16,0.43,7.5,29.9
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:03:06,"0","52",21.2,0.7,20.5,50.0,100.0,0.08,0.00,0.08,0.0,4.2
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:03:06,"1","52",245.6,233.4,12.2,73.7,100.0,2.08,1.83,0.25,8.0,21.4
... more lines after...
```

Output:

```
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:02:07,86.9,27.6,59.3,....
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:03:06,266.8,234.1,....
```

where: **86.9** is from: "50.0"(1st line) + 36.9 (2nd line). etc.. for each column.

Code with awk:

```
for TIME in $(awk -F ',|/' '{print $4","$5}' FILE | sort -u) ;do  echo -n "$TIME; awk -F ',' "/$TIME/ {SUM += \$6} END { print SUM}" FILE ; done
```

Many thanks for help

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I cannot make sense out of your first sentence.

Comment: sorry, i forgot it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk one-liner produces something close to the desired output:

```
$ awk -F, '{k=$1FS$2FS$3;seen[k];for(i=6;i<=NF;++i)sum[k,i]+=$i}END{for(i in seen){printf "%s,",i;for(j=6;j<=NF;++j)printf "%s%s",sum[i ,j],(j<NF?FS:RS)}}' file
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:03:06,266.8,234.1,32.7,123.7,200,2.16,1.83,0.33,8,25.6
RG Data,2015/02/27,18:02:07,86.9,27.6,59.3,45.5,200,0.82,0.19,0.63,13.8,34.4
```

The variable `k` is the key, which is made up the first, second and third columns of each line, joined on the field separator `FS` (a comma in this case). The array `seen` keeps track of every key `k` that is encountered.

The loop goes through each field from the sixth one to the last, adding to an element of the `sum` array, whose key is composed of the first two fields (as in `seen`) and the current field number.

Once the file has been processed, loop through the `seen` array and print out all of the corresponding elements of the `sum` array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom, nice awk command.., but in fact, there are several line with different time after. i edited my post.

Comment: Please see my modified script.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom!, your awk command works very well!! :)